# How to configure annotator and annotation modules in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, javascript, comments

I would like to provide an MS Word -like **annotations** (review comments) functionality in some text areas of my Drupal 7 website.

I have experimented with the [co.ment](https://drupal.org/project/co_ment) and [annotator](https://drupal.org/project/annotator) - [annotation](https://drupal.org/project/annotation) Drupal 7 modules, and the second solution seems lighter and more appropriate for my requirements.

Unfortunately there is very poor documentation on the annotator and annotation modules and I **cannot configure the storing** of my annotations.

I have read the annotator library [documentation](http://docs.annotatorjs.org/en/latest/index.html) but I do not know how to implement either the store or authentication and permissions plugins on my Drupal 7 website.

From the Annotator module page, what I understood is that by installing the **Store plugin** together with the Annotation module you use your own storing and not Annotateit.org service.

I have downloaded and installed the required libraries (annotator and Gettext) and from the Annotator configuration page I have enabled the Store plugin with the default Store url options. But my annotations do not get stored and I do not get any exceptions or other info, so that I can see what is going wrong.

Any suggestions please on what may be missing? I can provide more details where needed.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled across the same problem today. Proper way to install everything:

1. Download the annotator libraries in /sites/all/libraries/annotator
2. Download jquery_update and set jquery v.1.8 to be used
3. Download and enable the annotator module and its dependencies (e.g. libraries)
4. Download and enable the annotation module
5. Do not change any configuration options

For a minimal installation, I have just used the `markup` and `store` plugins. Some things that might get in the way of the annotations being saved:

- You need to have Clean URLs installed
- If Drupal is not installed in the root of your domain (for example if it's in http://example.com/subsite instead of http://example.com) you may have to change the configuration of the store plugin to point at /subsite/annotation/api instead of /annotation/api

You can manage the permissions to create, edit, view or delete annotations through the permission system of the annotation module.

Also, keep in mind, that if you create the annotation while you are browsing node/3 through the URL: `http://test.drupal/node/3#overlay-context=node/6`, the annotation **WILL NOT** appear if you visit: `http://test.drupal/node/3`. That caused me a lot of headaches. You can check whether your annotations have been saved in the `admin/content/annotation` path.

***NOTICE:***
When downloading the annotator library from github make sure that you download the annotator-full.1.2.9.zip not annotator.1.2.9.zip.